# Waiting threads will wait forever in Java InetAddress.getByName(String)

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, inetaddress

I'm experiencing that some threads keep waiting forever because of how the synchronization sections are organized in the snippet below.

The **lookupTable.wait();** is inside **synchronized (lookupTable)**, as the **lookupTable.notifyAll();** also it is. Though is impossible that while one thread is waiting, another one could send a **notifyAll()** in order to stop the wait.

This is a code snippet from the InetAddress class in the java.net package, and is executed when InetAddress.getByName(String) is called very often by around 100 threads. I'm trying to translate a bunch of hostnames into it's corresponding IP addresses.

Anyone has experienced the same?
Any advice will be welcome.

Thanks!

```
    private static InetAddress[] checkLookupTable(String host) {
        **synchronized (lookupTable)** {
            // If the host isn't in the lookupTable, add it in the
            // lookuptable and return null. The caller should do
            // the lookup.
            if (lookupTable.containsKey(host) == false) {
                lookupTable.put(host, null);
                return null;
            }

            // If the host is in the lookupTable, it means that another
            // thread is trying to look up the addresses of this host.
            // This thread should wait.
            while (lookupTable.containsKey(host)) {
                try {
                    **lookupTable.wait();**
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        // The other thread has finished looking up the addresses of
        // the host. This thread should retry to get the addresses
        // from the addressCache. If it doesn't get the addresses from
        // the cache, it will try to look up the addresses itself.
        InetAddress[] addresses = getCachedAddresses(host);
        if (addresses == null) {
            synchronized (lookupTable) {
                lookupTable.put(host, null);
                return null;
            }
        }

        return addresses;
    }

    private static void updateLookupTable(String host) {
        **synchronized (lookupTable)** {
            lookupTable.remove(host);
            **lookupTable.notifyAll();**
        }
    }
```

Comment: `put(host, null)` does not remove `host` from the map, so `containsKey(host)` still returns `true`...

Comment: Also, what if two threads look up the same host at the same time, and one succeeds? Then it never gets removed from lookupTable.

Comment: Yes, but the loop condition will exit when another thread executes lookupTable.remove(host); in the method  private static void updateLookupTable(String host), but this will never happen because the loop wait is inside the same synchronized(lookupTable).

Comment: sorry immibis, I didn't understand you at first time. You are right, this is exactly what it happens. This is the original code of the InetAddress class in JDK 1.8.